# Check redirect from

Tags: php

I have two files, checking.php contain code to check is it redirect from redirect.php, and print the corresponding message, redirect.php contain code to redirect to file A.

**checking.php**

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (!preg_match("/redirect.php/",$referrer)) {
    echo 'not redirect from redirect.php';
}
else
{
    echo 'is redirect from redirect.php';
}
```

**redirect.php**

```
header("location: http://abcdomain.com/checking.php");
exit();
```

But this is not working, please advice.

Comment: What is the nature of the problem.

Does checking.php not get loaded, or does checking.php display 'not redirect from redirect.php'?

One potential issue I see is that the "l" in "location" should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `header("location: http://abcdomain.com/checking.php");`wont set REFERRER, one possible solution is shown below(tested and works 100% fine)

**USE THIS IN REDIRECT.php**

```
echo "<script>parent.self.location='http://abcdomain.com/checking.php';</script>";
exit();
```

**This will set $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in checking.php**

Possible Reasons for this problem shown below

> Some browsers limit access to not allow HTTP_REFERER to be passed 
>     Type a address in the address bar will not pass the HTTP_REFERER 
>     open a new browser window will not pass the HTTP_REFERER, because HTTP_REFERER = NULL 
>     has some browser addon that blocks it for privacy reasons. 
> Some firewalls and AVs do to.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not redirecting at all for you, or redirecting, but printing the wrong message?  If it's not redirecting, try "Location:" upper-case.

It if is redirecting try `var_dump($_SERVER);` to see what is in it.